# Expected overshoot in a dice stopping problem

Tags: probability, dice

You throw a 6-sided dice and keep track of the sum $S$ of the rolls so far. Stop throwing when $S\geq N$ for some integer threshold $N$. What is $\mathbb{E}(S)$? (I'm in particular interested in the case $N$ going to infinity)

Note: for example, if $N=20$ and you throw $6, 4, 5, 6$, giving $S=21$, so you stop.

Intuitively, since the average roll is $3.5$, we can guess that $S-X$ is "roughly uniform between $0$ and $3.5$", giving a guess of $1.75$.

Motivation: Part of the problem from [here](https://80000hours.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/quant_trading_guide_v2.pdf) (Maths Problems, Q14).

Comment: From numerical experiments, it looks to me like $\ \mathbb{E}(S)\rightarrow\frac{5}{3}\ $ as $\ N\rightarrow\infty\ $.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera thank you for confirming the claim presented in the linked document. I wonder if there's a way to prove it?

Comment: My pologies. That should be $\ \mathbb{E}(S-N)=\frac{5}{3}\ $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a proof that $\ \mathbb{E}(S-N)\rightarrow\frac{5}{3}\ $.  Let $\ S_r\ $ be the sum after $\ r\ $ rolls.  Then the conditional expectation $e_j:= \mathbb{E}\big(S-N\,\big|\,S_r=j\,\big)\ $ is independent of $\ r\ $ as long as $\ r\le j\le 6r\ $ (it's undefined otherwise). Then
$$
\begin{align}
e_j&=\frac{1}{6}\sum_{i=1}^6e_{j+i}&&\text{ for } 0\le j\le N-1, \text{ and}\\
e_{N+i}&=i &&\text{ for } 0\le i\le 5.
\end{align}
$$
Solving the recurrence, it follows that
$$
e_j=c_0+\sum_{k=1}^5c_k\lambda_k^j\ ,
$$
where the recurrence has characteristic polynomial
\begin{align}
&x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x-6\\
&=(x-1)\big(x^5+2x^4+3x^3+4x^2+5x+6\big)\\
&=:(x-1)g(x)
\end{align}
and $\lambda_k$ are the roots of $g(x)$. Wolframalpha [tells us](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E5%2B2x%5E4%2B3x%5E3%2B4x%5E2%2B5x%2B6) that $g(x)$ has one real and two pairs of complex conjugate roots, all of which have absolute values strictly greater than $1$.

There are six initial conditions. We will combine them all to get $c_0$.

Let $\ f_j=e_j-c_0=\sum_\limits{k=1}^5c_k\lambda_k^j\ $. Then
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^5(6-i)f_{j+i}&=\sum_{i=0}^5(6-i)\sum_\limits{k=1}^5c_k\lambda_k^{j+i}\\
&=\sum_\limits{k=1}^5c_k\lambda_k^j\sum_{i=0}^5\underbrace{(6-i)\lambda_k^i}_{=g(\lambda_k) = 0} = 0.\\
\end{align}
In particular, letting $j = N$,
\begin{align}
0&=\sum_{i=0}^5(6-i)f_{N+i}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^5(6-i)\big(e_{N+i}-c_0\big)\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^5(6-i)i-21c_0\\
&=35-21c_0\ ,
\end{align}
so $\ c_0=\frac{5}{3}\ $.

The expectation we want is $\ e_0\ $, and we have
$$
e_{i+N}=i=\frac{5}{3}+\sum_{k=1}^5c_k\lambda_k^{i+N}
$$
for $\ 0\le i\le5\ $, or
$$
\pmatrix{-\frac{5}{3}\\-\frac{2}{3}\\\frac{1}{3}\\\frac{4}{3}\\\frac{7}{3}\\\frac{10}{3}}=\pmatrix{1&1&\dots&1\\
\lambda_1&\lambda_2&\dots&\lambda_5\\
\lambda_1^2&\lambda_2^2&\dots&\lambda_5^2\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
\lambda_1^5&\lambda_2^5&\dots&\lambda_5^5}\pmatrix{c_1\lambda_1^N\\c_2\lambda_2^N\\\vdots\\c_5\lambda_5^N}\ .
$$
Since the roots $\ \lambda_k\ $ are all distinct, the transposed [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) on the right of this equation is invertible.  Therefore, if
$$
\pmatrix{d_1\\d_2\\\vdots\\d_5}=\pmatrix{1&1&\dots&1\\
\lambda_1&\lambda_2&\dots&\lambda_5\\
\lambda_1^2&\lambda_2^2&\dots&\lambda_5^2\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
\lambda_1^5&\lambda_2^5&\dots&\lambda_5^5}^{-1}\pmatrix{-\frac{5}{3}\\-\frac{2}{3}\\\frac{1}{3}\\\frac{4}{3}\\\frac{7}{3}\\\frac{10}{3}}\  
$$
we have $\ c_k=d_k\lambda_k^{-N}\ $ and
$$
e_0=\frac{5}{3}+\sum_{k=1}^5d_k\lambda_k^{-N}\rightarrow\frac{5}{3}\ \ \text{as }\ N\rightarrow\infty\ .
$$

Comment: Brilliant solution! Nicely exploited the properties of the recurrence and the characteristic polynomial. This problem is unusual in the sense that the "initial conditions" are at the end of the recurrence.

Answer (score 3):

It might be helpful to think of how we can have an overshoot:

- the ways to overshoot of $5$ is $1$ (being at (S-1) then rolling $6$)
- the ways to overshoot of $4$ is $2$ ((S-1) + $5$ and (S-2) + $6$)
- the ways to overshoot of $3$ is $3$
- the ways to overshoot of $2$ is $4$
- the ways to overshoot of $1$ is $5$
- the ways to overshoot of $0$ is $6$

I think it is most natural to understand that every way from the above ways to overshoot is equally likely as $N$ tends to ${\infty}$, but I'm unsure how to show this formally.

We have then $21$ ways to overshoot, with the the total sum of overshoot of $35$. yielding $35/21$ or **$5/3$** as the average overshoot.

Comment: Thanks! This does make intuitive sense. I will try to formalise your answer using a Markov chain on $\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ with transition probabilities $1/6$ globally. Think of $0$ as the threshold. For example, going from $5$ to $1$ is equivalent to rolling a $2$ and overshooting by $1$, because you go $(5)\rightarrow 0\rightarrow 1$. Now, the average overshoot is simply $$\mathbb{E}(x_n|x_n \leq x_{n-1})$$ for large n.